# How do I check if my dates have a certain year, after retrieving all dates via php?

Tags: php

I am retrieving my date like this in my php query:

```
DATE_FORMAT(items.r_date, '%M %D, %Y') as r_date
```

And then displaying it like this,  for example:

```
January 1st, 1934
```

However, if the year is 1111, I would like to make the date say something custom.

Such as (I know this isn't real code, just trying to explain what I want to do:

```
if ($row['r_date'] CONTAINS '*1111*') { $r_date = "my custom message"; } else $r_date = $row['r_date'];
```

Could anyone help me solve this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thank you all, how do I pick an answer when they all work well?!

Comment: well ignore the date ones, as your just dealing with a string, and have no need for the 'power' they bring. For the 2 sting answers one checks the whole string for your year, one only check the last 4 digits, you decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal implementation of your pseudo-code uses [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
if (false !== strpos($row['r_date'], '1111')) {
    $r_date = "my custom message";
} else {
    $r_date = $row['r_date'];
}
```

However, the "only check the last four digits" [answer by Dagon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39113252/2908724), or the alternate one below using [substr_compare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-compare.php), may yield fewer false positives:

```
if (0 === substr_compare(rtrim($row['r_date']), '1111')) 
    $r_date = "my custom message";
} else {
    $r_date = $row['r_date'];
}
```

Note I've used [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) here in the event your date has spurious white-space on the end.

Answer (score 2):

i would use substr() to extract the last 4 characters being your year

```
if (substr($row['r_date'], -4) != '1111') { 
    $r_date = $row['r_date']; } 
else { 
    $r_date = "my custom message"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if u only want to check by its year, then :

```
    $mydate = date('Y', strtotime($row['r_date']))
    if ($mydate == '1111' or $mydate == '1970') {
    echo "something";
    }else{
    echo "else"
    }
```

note:
Y = for 4 digit year.
y = for 2 digit year.
1970 is the lower year on system, so if your year is lower than 1970 system will make year to 1970 by default.

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). 
I didn't test but it should be something similar, just change the date format:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m-d-Y", "02-01-1111");
if($date->format("Y")=="1111")
    echo "your custom message";
```